# BERT as a service for classification?

Tags: text, nlp, classification

I have fine-tuned BERT on a classification task.

bert-as-a-service allows getting word embeddings but I would like to get the class of an input text.

The problem is best described here:
https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service/issues/213

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Use Bert as service to featurize, then build a simple classifier with them

Comment: Thanks! If I have a trained model would  that require training the classifier again?

Comment: Meaning, if you train the classifier from the BERT-as-Service (BaS) output, then you change the BERT mode that BaS uses, do you need to retrain the classifier? If that's what you mean, then yes

Comment: Hi, no. Bert as a service gives a vector not class. I have a fine tune model

Comment: Weaviate has a semantic classification function: https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/classification/contextual-classification.html

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Bert-as-a-Service is to produce the sentence embeddings similar to ELMo, not serve as a classifier.

To use BERT for classification after fine-tuning one can use the implementation given in the following link:

https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb